# Plot the histogram of buy ratio as a function of the day of the week and time of the day

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataframe with 34154695 obs. In a dataset a Class variable with value 0 indicate "not purchased" and 1 indicate "purchase".

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   34154695 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ SessionID: int  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ Timestamp: Factor w/ 34069144 levels "2014-04-01T03:00:00.124Z",..: 1452469 1452684 1453402 1501801 1501943 1502207 1502429 1502569 1502932 295601 ...
 $ ItemID   : int  214536500 214536506 214577561 214662742 214662742 214825110 214757390 214757407 214551617 214716935 ...
 $ Category : Factor w/ 339 levels "0","1","10","11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Class    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I am facing difficulties finding a solution to plot a histogram of the number of purchase per week, per day and time wise purchase based on class value = 1 and wanna output like this show in images below.

[image]
[image]

I tried this code but got error

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)



x <- strptime(data$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d")#assume you need only days/month , assign to a variable, because dplyr has problems with with date type.

data$month <- month(x) #get month from date obj.

month_summ <- data %>% group_by(month) %>%  #group by month and calculated sold items per month
  summarise(
    total_sales = n()
  )


library(ggplot2)



 ggplot(data=month_summ, aes(x=month, y=ItemID)) +   geom_bar(stat="identity") #plot the histogram
```

Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column date is of unsupported class POSIXlt/POSIXt

Could someone please inform how I should proceed?? Really, thank you for any help and suggesting.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not completely clear but the following code produces two graphs, one of total `Class` per `Weekday` and the other of total `Class` per hour of day.
I first coerce column `Class` to class `"integer"`, in your output of `str(data)` it is a `"factor"`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data$Class <- as.integer(as.character(data$Class))

data$Weekday <- format(data$Timestamp, "%a")
data$Hour <- hour(data$Timestamp)
```

Now the graphs. First by weekday.

```
aggregate(Class ~ Weekday, data, sum) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Weekday, Class)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

And by hour.

```
aggregate(Class ~ Hour, data, sum) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Hour, Class)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

**Edit.**

The graphs above can also be produced without modifying the original dataset `data`. They will be produce as the result of a bigger pipe but it is perhaps simpler or preferable to do it like the following.
Starting with the original data.

```
data$Class <- as.integer(as.character(data$Class))

data %>%
  mutate(Weekday = format(Timestamp, "%a")) %>%
  group_by(Weekday) %>%
  summarise(Class = sum(Class)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Weekday, Class)) +
  geom_col()

data %>%
  mutate(Hour = hour(Timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(Hour) %>%
  summarise(Class = sum(Class)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Hour, Class)) +
  geom_col()
```

**Data generation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
n <- 1e3
start <- as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 00:00:00")
end <- Sys.time()
Timestamp <- sample(seq(start, end, by = "min"), n, TRUE)
Class <- factor(sample(0:1, n, TRUE))
data <- data.frame(Timestamp, Class)
```

Comment: @mairakhan Glad it helped. In the mean time I have thought of a pipe `%>%` only solution. See the edit.

Comment: sir one more thing ....how to  plot clicks on a given item in a session, item duration in a session (seconds) and session duration (minutes) .

Comment: @mairakhan How many sessions are there? What is the output of `length(unique(data$SessionID))`?

Comment: the output of is mentioned here > length(unique(data$SessionID)) [1] 9249729